# Why can't I pass constant arrays as arguments?

Tags: c, arguments, parameter-passing, compound-literals

In C, why can't I do this:

```
arrayfn({1.0, 2.0, 3.0});
```

if `arrayfn` is some function that takes in one parameter of type `double[]` or `double*`, whichever. Trying this gives me a syntax error.

Is there a way that I could achieve something in C like this - generating and immediately passing an array known at compile time - that avoids having to spend a line of code pre-declaring and filling it?

Comment: You can use a compound literal.

Comment: good answer; tried it; it works; we're done here

Comment: We're not done until you accept an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer:** You need to make use of a [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html). Something like

```
 arrayfn( (double[]) {1.0, 2.0, 3.0} );
```

should do the job.

---

**Some explanation**

Coming to the part, why `arrayfn({1.0, 2.0, 3.0});` did not work, because, without the syntax for compound literals, `{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}` is a brace enclosed initializer list. It does not denote an "object" which can be used as function argument. They are **not** *"constant arrays"*, as you may have thought.

To add some more info, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.5, *Compound literals*

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace-enclosed
>   list of initializers is a compound literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Bit weird that my immediate impulse was to run `(double*){1.0, 2.0, 3.0}`, which didn't do what I wanted it to do - but close enough!

Comment: @user3528438: The `const` is optional; the compound literal is not a constant array unless you want it to be one.  It can be modified by the code in the called function completely legitimately.